# Helm Chart configmap templating with toYaml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have **values.yml** file that takes in a list of mountPaths with this format:

```
global:
  mountPath:
    hello:
      config: /etc/hello/hello.conf
      node: /opt/hello/node.jks
      key: /opt/hello/key.jks
      cert: /opt/hello/cert.jks
```

I want the resulting rendered template to be

```
      volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/hello/hello.conf
          subPath: config
        - name: node
          mountPath: /opt/hello/node.jks
          subPath: node
        - name: key
          mountPath: /opt/hello/key.jks
          subPath: key
        - name: cert
          mountPath: /opt/hello/cert.jks
          subPath: cert
```

How would I accomplish this? I tried the following in my **deployment.yaml** template file:

```
      volumeMounts:
      {{- range $key, $value := pluck .Values.service_name .Values.global.mountPath.serviceName | first }}
        - name: {{ $key }}
          mountPath: $value
          subPath: {{ $key }}
      {{- end }}
```

the following helm command that i have run but the it won't work for me. How do I accomplish getting to the format I want above based on the input?

```
helm upgrade --install \
  --namespace ${NAMESPACE} \
  --set service_name=hello \
  --set namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
  hello . \
  -f values.yaml \
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ` mountPath: {{ $value }}`?

Comment: If you change `helm upgrade --install` to `helm template` but otherwise keep the same options, it will print out the YAML it renders.  What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:

```
      volumeMounts:
      {{- range $key, $value := pluck .Values.service_name .Values.global.mountPath | first }}
        - name: {{ $key }}
          mountPath: {{  $value }}
          subPath: {{ $key }}
      {{- end }}
```

`helm template --set service_name=hello [...]`  seems to render exactly what you want.

Notice I changed the line with mountPath field:  `$value` -> `{{ $value }}`,
and the line with range: `.Values.global.mountPath.serviceName` -> `.Values.global.mountPath`